# `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

Tags: mysql, mariadb, homestead

I've recently upgrade my homestead to latest release (Ubuntu 16.04) and reinitialize all homestead.yaml, etc.

I've put: `mariadb: true` inside Homestead.yaml. Everything installed perfectly and running normally. 
But after sometime mysql will stop by itself.

Error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

I've tried  `sudo services mysql reload`.  its working back to normal but start shutting down after few minutes.

Before upgrading everything is working perfectly.

Any suggestion? I've tried re-provision still no hope.

Comment: Did you check the database/system logs to find out what is causing the shutdown?

Comment: dup of unresolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270617/how-should-i-resolve-the-error-cantt-connect-to-local-sql-server-through-socke , plus lots of others.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Try installing virtualbox version 5.0.18 https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0
and then run

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: Did this vagrant reload --provision got the error and just ran command again and it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

apparmor was the culprit. Despite the contents of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` being nothing but comments and claiming that it was there so that apparmor wouldn't choke on MariaDB, that's exactly what was happening.

[AppArmor and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql) on an Oracle blog provided what I needed to figure out what was going on.

`sudo aa-status` shows you what apparmor is doing; what actually has an enforced policy, versus what's just set to complain.

`sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils` adds a few commands that make the apparmor profiles easier to deal with, such as...

`sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` turns the profile from "enforce" to complain. (`aa-enforce` turns it back.)

Once that's done, `sudo service apparmor reload` restarts apparmor, and voila... `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` works, and the server stays up.

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/750604/why-does-mariadb-keep-dying-how-do-i-stop-it